# Bash - Counter for multiple parameters in file

Tags: bash

I created a command, which works, but not exactly as I want. So I would like to upgrade this command to right output.

My command:

```
awk '{print $1}' ios-example.com.access | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Output of my command:

```
8 192.27.69.191
2 82.202.69.253
```

Input file:
https://pajda.fit.vutbr.cz/ios/ios-19-1-logs/blob/master/ios-example.com.access.log

Output I need(hashtags instead of numbers):

```
198.27.69.191 (8): ########
82.202.69.253 (2): ##
```

Comment: what does the input file look like?

Comment: awk '{print $1}' file - output would be full of ip adress

Comment: @Zakys98 I see you are new here, but it is best to give us sample of input. I assumed that numbers in front were from input (8 and 2), but they came from `uniq -c` haven't they?

Comment: @Gox ok, sorry, i have already posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat ios-example.com.access | sort | uniq -c | awk 'ht="#"{for(i=1;i<$1;i++){ht=ht"#"} str=sprintf("%s (%d): %s", $2,$1, ht); print str}'
```

expecting file with content like:

```
ipadress1
ipadress1
ipadress1
ipadress2
ipadress2
ipadress1
ipadress2
ipadress1
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your command by adding another `awk` to the list, or you can just use a single awk for the whole thing:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}
     END { for(i in a) { 
             printf "%s (%d):" ,i,a[i]
             for(j=0;j<a[i];++j) printf "#"; printf "\n"
           }
     }' file
```

Comment: The output is: not enough arguments to satisfy format string

Comment: @Zakys98 sorry missed a comma

Comment: where ? i dont see it

Comment: @Zakys98 it was in the first printed statement but already corrected

Comment: yes, but i dont see what you have just repaired and i wanna know

Comment: @Zakys98 the comma before the `i` was missing. Printf was expecting 2 args but received only one. The missing comma made awk interprete `"%s (%d):" i` as a string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs` with `sh` and `printf`. Comments in between the lines. Live version at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/c5b6VA).

```
# sorry cat
cat <<EOF |
8 192.27.69.191
2 82.202.69.253
EOF
# for each 2 arguments
xargs -n2 sh -c '
    # format the output as "$2 ($1): "
    printf "%s (%s): " "$2" "$1"
    # repeat the character `#` $1 times
    seq "$1" | xargs printf "#%.0s"
    # lastly a newline
    printf "\n"
' --
```

I think we could shorten that a bit with:

```
xargs -n2 sh -c 'printf "%s (%s): %s\n" "$2" "$1" $(printf "#%.0s" $(seq $1))' --
```

or maybe just echo, if the input is sufficiently safe:

```
xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo "$2 ($1): $(printf "#%.0s" $(seq $1))"' --
```